# Is it possible to bind multiple, simulated devices to SNMP port 161?

Tags: port, emulator, snmp, bindings

I am attempting to simulate multiple SNMP agents on my computer. I am using [this software](http://www.veraxsystems.com/en/products/snmpsimulator) to try and accomplish this.

From the program's description:

> Verax SNMP agent simulator is a tool that can simulate multiple
>   SNMPv1/v2c agents on a single host on standard 161 port through
>   multi-netting.

I am able to have one device up and running using the following type settings:

```
<type filepath="C:\vxsnmpsimulator\conf\..\device\os\os-linux-std.txt" state="stopped">
    <devices>
        <device ip="192.168.9.66" netmask="20" port="161"></device>
    </devices>
</type>
```

However, if I add a second device...

```
<types>
    <type filepath="C:\vxsnmpsimulator\conf\..\device\os\os-linux-std.txt" state="stopped">
        <devices>
            <device ip="192.168.9.66" netmask="20" port="161"></device>
        </devices>
    </type>
    <type filepath="C:\vxsnmpsimulator\conf\..\device\cisco\cisco_router.txt" state="stopped">
        <devices>
            <device ip="192.168.9.67" netmask="20" port="161"></device>
        </devices>
    </type>
</types>
```

I see the following message in my logs:

> 2012-06-19 10:58:16.339 ERROR [com.veraxsystems.SimulatorSNMPAgent.Agent                             ] Start agent [192.168.9.67/161]: Cannot assign requested address: Cannot bind
>   2012-06-19 10:58:16.339 INFO

I see numerous, commercial programs which advertise simulating 10-50,000 SNMP agents. I am wondering how they accomplish this if only one device is allowed to bind to 161.

I had read that when dealing with UDP it was possible to have multiple devices listen on the same port. This isn't the same as binding to the port, though, so I am not sure if that knowledge is applicable to this endeavour.

Comment: Why is your netmask 20? if you meant to make it a /20, the netmask would be 255.255.240.0, but it looks like it's trying to bind to a specific IP. So wouldn't you be trying to make sure the netmask was 255.255.255.0?